# Use AnimationLoop() from another function

Tags: reactjs, three.js

In my Three.JS project i've just recentley moved my Mesh into a seperate file and therfor my 'startAnimationLoop()' function can no long reach the values to make my mesh(a simple cube) rotate.

**Mesh.JS**

```
import * as THREE from "three";

export default ({ scene, cube }) => {
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 2);
    const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x156289, emissive: 
    0x072534, side: THREE.DoubleSide, flatShading: true, wireframe: false});
    cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);

  }
```

**The imported Mesh**

```
import Mesh from './Mesh'

  componentDidMount() {
    this.sceneSetup();
    this.startAnimationLoop();
    Mesh({ scene: this.scene, cube: this.cube });
    Lightss({ scene: this.scene, light: this.lightning })
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleWindowResize);
  }
```

**The Animation Function**

```
  startAnimationLoop = () => {
    this.cube.rotation.x += 0.01;  /* DOESNT WORK */ 
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    this.requestID = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.startAnimationLoop);
  };
```

How can i reach the **cube** 
From the **Mesh** 
Inside my **startAnimationLoop()** function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this issue:

- Give your mesh a descriptive name e.g. `cube.name = 'myCube';`
- In the file with your animation loop, create a module scope variable called `cube`.
- Use [Object3D.getObjectByName()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.getObjectByName) to query the mesh from your scene graph like so: `cube = this.scene.getObjectByName( 'myCube' );`
- For performance reasons, it's important to perform this query only once and then buffer the object in a variable.

`three.js R108`

Comment: What a nice way to reach the cube! But i get the following:
const cube = this.scene.getObjectByName('myCube') //This is ok.
this.cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
when i try to add the rotation i get the following typeError:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'rotation' of undefined

Any suggestions?

Comment: Solved! i called the animation function before the initialise of the object.
Thank you Mugen!